# ESQL to send attachments using a SOAP request node in IBM Integration Bus

Tags: websphere, ibm-integration-bus

Can anyone please tell me the ESQL code for sending an attachment using a SOAP request node in IIB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SOAP with Attachment, then you can provide attachments and metadata for those in the OutputRoot.SOAP.Attachment subtree:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac64020_.htm?lang=en

If you want to use MTOM, then the attachments are represented inline, within the body of the message, so you need to set the field(s) in your message containing base64Binary data:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56630_.htm?lang=en